# Register BroadcastReceiver in activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have checkboxlist where the user can select some Interger items. Afterwards the alarmManger starts firing to the `IntentService` class. A request is being sent to the server and then I am getting reponse. Next I get the data from the response and then what I am trying to achieve is  to send the data to the Map activity without stoping the alarmManager firing in the MainActivity.

I have tried it before by passing the intent directly to the `Map` activity but the alarmManger  stops firing. Therefore I want to send a broadcast Intent with the data from the IntentService to the Map subsequently the `Map` Activity can register the BroadcastRecevier to listen for this but I am facing problem to register the `data_receiver` in the Map activity. How can I register the `data_receiver` int the `Map` activity in this case?

**in the GetLLRD (IntentService) class I have the following.**

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
                try {
                    //here I am getting the data from the server json response.
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType);

                    if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
                        final ArrayList<ItemDTO> test = data;

                        final BroadcastReceiver data_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceive(Context context,
                                    Intent intent) {
                                Intent intent1 = new Intent(GetLLRD.this,
                                        Map.class);
                                intent1.putExtra("list_data", test);
                                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent1);

                            }

                        };

                    } else {
                        Log.e("123",
                                "Avoiding null pointer, the dat is null in the GETLLRD class!!!");
                    }

                } 
}
```

**Map activity:**

public class Map  extends ActionBarActivity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_main);

    IntentFilter data_action= new IntentFilter();
    // Which action have I to add here?
    data_action.addAction();
    // And how to define data_receiver here since I am getting: data_receiver cannot be resolved to a variable
    registerReceiver(data_receiver, data_action);

    Intent intent = getIntent();        
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     ArrayList<ItemDTO> list =(ArrayList<ItemDTO>) intent.getSerializableExtra("list_data");

        }
}
```

}

Comment: anything that is unique to the whole system, use your package name as a prefix for example

Comment: @pskink: do you mean there is no need for the `data_receiver` and  I should try to pass the intent to the map activity with the `package name as a prefix `?

Comment: you can use BroadcastReceiver, i didnt say there is no need for it

Comment: @pskink: can I put my `intent1` in this way in the `data_receiver` without using the intent or the context parameter of the `onReceive()`?

Comment: no idea what you mean

Comment: @pskink: I mean when I use the `public void onReceive(Context context,
Intent intent)` I am not using the `intent , context ` parameters in the method body. Is that ok or I have to use the `intent` of the onReceive since I dont need them in my case?

Comment: yes it is ok, you dont need to use the params